# Reduxjs Toolkit with Login Slice in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I just started learning redux and realized that they reconfigured the framework to work in a different way, that is the `@reduxjs/toolkit`

I am trying to create a loginSlice for when a user tries to login. but I am not sure of how it works since im new to redux and this new way of redux is new.

I wanted to know if my below code is the right approach.

Here is my code:

loginSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const loginSlice = createSlice({
    name: "login",
    initialState: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    },
    reducers: {
        onLogin: (state, action) => {
          email.value = action.payload,
          password.value = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { onLogin } = loginSlice.actions
export default loginSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if login function called like :

```
dispatch(
    onLogin({
    email: 'OsamaJamal@O.com'
    password: 'Osama'
    })
)
```

so your code will be:

```
        onLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.email = action.payload.email,
      state.password = action.payload.password
    }
```

more [details](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

**Add login process**

```
        initialState: {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        userData : {},
},


      onLogin: (state, action) => {
      const { email, password } = action.payload;
      axios.post('domain/login' , {email , password}).then((res)=>{
      if(res.user){
      state.userData = res.user
    }
      })
        }
```